# Remarkable creates &lt; for <

Tags: javascript, markdown

I use Remarkable to change Markdown into HTML; https://github.com/jonschlinkert/remarkable

The goal is to create a knowledge base with code snippets, stored in .md files, shown in HTML in the webbrowser.

The issue that I have is within code-blocks, with single or triple back-ticks. The `<` and the `>` signs that are translated to `&lt;` and `&gt;` or even in other ways, making the code-blocks useless for non-HTML. Stange enough, known HTML tags stay untouched within the pre/code blocks and therefore are shown correctly.

Like in Powershell, you can have a block-comment like:

```
<#
  some text
#>
```

But using Remarkable, **in a pre/code block**, this is changed into

```
&lt;#
  some text
#&gt;
```

Also if I mark the code-block as powershell by using  ```` ```powershell ````, so this makes the code-snippets useless.

But `<strong>someText</strong>` in a code block stays in the same way and therefor will be shown correctly.

The Markdown data is echo'd by PHP within a div-block:

```
<div id="markdown"><?php echo $data; ?></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var md = new Remarkable();
var result = md.render(document.getElementById("markdown").innerHTML);
document.getElementById("markdown").innerHTML = result;
```

Comment: Why would you assume you have an error? Do the Remarkable docs say that this is supported? (because that's definitely not CommonMark syntax, and is not mentioned in the supported extensions)

Comment: Encoding < is correct when you target HTML, `&lt;` means “<“ in HTML. Line break tags etc. are explicitly ignored.

Comment: You convert Markdown to HTML. You want valid HTML. If you have code blocks, you want HTML which has code markup and within that you want valid HTML. A `<` in HTML must be encoded to `&lt;`, **unless it's the start of a tag.** It's not the start of a tag here, it's just a "<". So it's encoded to `&lt;`. Actual inline HTML is explicitly allowed by Markdown: https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html

Comment: You've got something very wrong here. How would you demonstrate with a pre-code block how an HTML pre-code block works? `<pre><code>Try this: <pre><code>foo</code></pre></code></pre>`. You do see that those end tags are ambiguous? For this reason it _must_ be written as `<pre><code>Try this: &lt;pre>&lt;code>foo&lt;/code>&lt;/pre></code></pre>`. And it will be rendered *not* as `&lt;pre>` but as `<pre>`.

Comment: That `<#...` block doesn't appear to be particularly marked up as code in any way…!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After giving up with Remarkable, I tried MarkedJS and Markdown-it, what gave the same result... Then I found out, it was not Remarkable who was doing difficult, but it's because of the way I read the data; by using `innerHTML`.

`innerHTML` does *in some cases* change the `<` and `>` and other characters... also `<?php` is changed into `<!--php` for instance. This was a total surprise for me !

By adding `console.log(result);` in my small JS code, I was able to see with Google Inspect (F12), tab Console the actual content of `result` before it is send to Remarkable.

As I am not able to "fix" this by myself, I choose to "avoid" this issue by not reading the file-content by PHP inside the div, but by using Javascript to read the file, converting the content to html and then send the result to an empty div.

```
<div id="markdown"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadFile(filePath) {
        var result = null;
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", filePath, false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        if (xmlhttp.status==200) {
            result = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        return result;
    }

    var md = new Remarkable();
    var source = loadFile("<?php echo $file; ?>");
    var result = md.render(source);
    document.getElementById("markdown").innerHTML = result;
</script>
```

⚠️ I am aware that in this way, my source file is easily visible and readable, in my case no problem, but please keep this in mind if you want to read a file in Javascript in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Every "<" character in HTML must be encoded to `&lt;`, **unless it's the start of a tag.** What you have there is not the start of a tag, it's just a "<" character. You want that "<" character to render as "<", not to be interpreted as an HTML tag. So it's being encoded to `&lt;`.

This:

```
&lt;#
  some text
  some other text
#&gt;
```

will render as this in the browser:

> <#
>   some text
>   some other text
> #>

Proof:

```html
<pre>
<code>
&lt;#
  some text
  some other text
#&gt;
</code>
</pre>
```

---

Inline HTML is [**explicitly allowed** in Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html), so legitimate `<br>` tags and such are *not encoded*:

> For any markup that is not covered by Markdown’s syntax, you simply use HTML itself. There’s no need to preface it or delimit it to indicate that you’re switching from Markdown to HTML; you just use the tags.

Comment: `<pre>` blocks do not suspend HTML parsing. I have updated my example to show that. HTML tags within `pre` blocks are still parsed as HTML. How else would you write "<pre></pre>" inside a `<pre>` block if you wanted to demonstrate how HTML pre-blocks work?

Comment: It's closed for *two* reasons, one of which is the requirement for a clear, simple, reproducible example.